# LinearLayout with RelativeLayout having imageView inside don't respect weight constraint

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I don't understand how the ImageView size works on a relative layout having weight defined

This is my code:

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".CameraActivity" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="76" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imagePreview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/photo_placeholder" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/timeButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="Button" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="24" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/mainButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="#0fff"
            android:src="@drawable/cam_main_btn_normal" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/nextButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
            android:background="#0fff"
            android:src="@drawable/gs_05_check_normal" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
            android:background="#0fff"
            android:src="@drawable/cam_cancel" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and I get 
[image: Wrong result]
but if I remove the image it shows dimentions correctly as I expect
[image: Result without imageView]

So the question is, how should I do to get the imageView to take the full space respecting the weight on the relative layout?

I tried to change the android:layout_width, android:layout_height of the imageView to wrap_content (make no sense, but just' checking) it doesn't work.
I tried with and without scaleType, and different values, doesn't change.

I guess ImageView needs some trick/magic?

-- EDIT -- 
I'm expecting that the image will take the size highligted in blue on the second screenshoot :)
-- EDIT --
What I want to achieve:
[image: The result I want to achieve]

Comment: android:weightSum=100 on the parent LinearLayout?

Comment: This problem exists with a simple View too

Comment: @DavidOlsson unfortunately I already tried that and it doen't work.

Comment: @gigigan can you give me the photo_placeholder and gs_05_check_normal image?I want to test.I have tested without it all seems to be correct.

Comment: What are you expecting, the `Button` to be above the `ImageView`?

Comment: @codeMagic no, I'm expecting that the image will take the size highligted in blue on the second screenshoot

Comment: @Pratik images can be found here: [images github](https://github.com/gigigan/creamly/tree/gh-pages/images)

Comment: I see. I don't know if it will make a difference but you should be using `dp` instead of `px` for the `height`

Comment: @codeMagic I know =) I always put px when using 0 to see it more quickly in the XML

Comment: It seems to me weight is working you just have to provide other values. You can use a RelativeLayout as a parent and for the second RelativeLayout use wrap_content and for the first use match_parent and above second relative layout. I would suggest you to use LinearLayout with weights instead of the second relative layout (the distance between buttons will be the same on multimple screens).Hope it helps!

Comment: a better solution is to put weighted imageViews in Linear Layout,which may be in Relative Layout.
i can't exetly understanding your problem.,what exet u want to say???
i can help you.

Comment: @Rumit I want the image to take the highlighted position of the second screen shot, that second screen is the same XML code than posted without the ImageView, adding the imageView screw everything.

Comment: Thank you all, it seems to be a bug of eclispe preview thing as it works on the device. I did not have a chance to test it before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

still not getting what you are trying,your way to working with weight is may be wrong.
but try this demo,
hope it will help you to understand weight.

**just paste it into xml.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".80" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".20" >

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="33.33"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="33.33"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="33.33"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

still if any query about weight,then plz ask.

Comment: Upper Relative layout is 80%, and lawar Linear Layout is 20%.
same as lawer Layout has 3 same part of 33.33%.

Comment: Nice example to under stand the layout_width.+1 brother for nice example.

Comment: The 0dp height did the trick for me. Android is so stupid sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

In fact that code was good and it's more of an eclipse "preview" bug as it works on device (did not have a chance to test before)

Sorry all